# $A_{\infty}$-category structure on $D^b {Coh}(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In S.Barannikov's article, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903124.pdf, the author states (in page 13) that:

(X is a Calabi-Yau manifold) One of the ways to describe the $A_{\infty}$-category structure on $D^b {Coh}(X)$ is to identify it with the category which is obtained from the differential graded category of finitely generated projective modules over the algebra $\mathcal{A}_X=\left(\Omega^{0, *}(X), \bar{\partial}\right)$ by taking the same collection of objects and by taking $H^0$ of the complex ${Hom}^*\left(\mathcal{E}_1^*, \mathcal{E}_2^*\right)$ as the linear space of morphisms between two objects $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2$. Then one can use the homotopy technic (see for example [M,P]) to construct the $A_{\infty}$-category structure on $D^b {Coh}(X)$. The $A_{\infty}$-category $D^b {Coh}(X)$ is $A_{\infty}$-equivalent to the category of finitely generated projective modules over $\mathcal{A}_X$.

My question is, how is the first step (the identification between $D^b {Coh}(X)$ and the category which is obtained (how to obtain ?)from the differential graded category of finitely generated projective modules over the algebra $\mathcal{A}_X=\left(\Omega^{0, *}(X), \bar{\partial}\right)$) achieved? I know that the category of coherent sheaves $Coh(A)$ is equivalent to the category of finitely generated $A$-modules if $A$ is noetherian (Hartshorne. Cor 5.5). But how to apply this on a Calabi-Yau manifold? I have no idea know how to proceed and how the projective module comes. Any references or hints would also be helpful.